# "Migrate" from the classic java.util.Date type of a property to an equivalent type of java.time

Tags: java, datetime, java.util.date, java-time

What is the appropriate type to declare a date property that represents a `DATETIME` field in database.

The purpose of the question is to see whether I could use `java.time` instead of `java.util.Date` in the Date properties on an entity that I am currently building, since some of the `java.util.Date` methods are deprecated and it is generally suggested to use `java.time`.

Comment: Database will require java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp.   That hasn't changed.  You should be able to create a java.time equivalent easily.

Comment: @duffymo You are right. Do you think `java.time.Instant` would be compatible with `java.sql.Date` or at least `java.sql.Timestamp` ?

Comment: I think Instant would be the choice for TIMESTAMP and LocalDate for a simple yyyy-MMM-dd.

Answer (score 2):

For a `DATE` value with a time, where you'd have used JDBC type [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). There are methods to help converting:

```
LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();

Date sqlDate = Date.valueOf(localDate);
```

For a `TIMESTAMP` / `DATETIME` value, where you'd have used JDBC type [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), it depends on your whether you need to consider time zone.

If the application, its users, and the database are all in the same time zone, you can use [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). There are methods to help converting:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = timestamp.toLocalDateTime();

Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
```

If users are in multiple time zones, you should always save values to database in UTC, so you should use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). There are methods to help converting:

```
Instant instant = timestamp.toInstant();

Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(instant);
```

You may then want to convert to the user's local time zone for display, e.g.:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
LocalDateTime localDateTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime();
```